# Internet Explorer Extension to Configure a New Device

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, browser-extension

I am trying to write an extension to configure a new device that we use for work. This device is used to restart any devices that are connected to it. It has a static IP address which you use to access and configure the device. There are usually more than one of these devices that need configured at a site. This extension will be used in conjunction with another application (built in VB.NET) that will gather user input and configure the PC.

Ideally I am looking to complete the following actions using an extension:

1. Read string information from a file or registry that was output from the application
2. Fill in forms including username and password information
3. Click submit button automatically
4. Added bonus: I would like to include the extension and my application as a single file

I think I figured out how to do 2 and 3. Step 2 would use HTML DOM and step 3 would use javascript to click the submit button. Step 1 I am less sure how to do. I found some information at [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) but I am use how to use this information to read data from a path that will never change (I don't need the upload button).

So given all of this information what I really want to know is if I am on the right path and if I can even accomplish what I want with an extension. In the case where an extension will not work what else could I use to accomplish this task? I am open to using other browsers if they will accomplish what I want however, I chose IE because it is already installed on the PC and I am hoping that I can include my VB.NET application and the extension in a single file.

I don't usually develop in HTML so please keep things geared toward beginner level.
Thanks.

Comment: You can do just about everything with an extension if you manage to request the right permissions (it won't let you read from a file or registry if not requested correctly). But, what happens if someone is on Linux or Mac? Internet Explorer is rarely installed on these OS, if ever. Keep it up, and once you get something to work with, feel free to ask a more specific question so we can help you with the code if there is problems with it.

Comment: I would avoid writing any browser extension for this unless there are requirements that you haven't mentioned. Why not just use your VB.NET application to handle all of these tasks? It will be much simpler and less fragile.

Comment: We do not have any Mac or Linux machines so I am not worried about them. As for using VB.NET I was not aware I could manipulate forms in Internet Explorer from a VB.NET application. Could you provide more information on this?

Comment: Why do you need Internet Explorer to be involved at all? If you're trying to show a Web Page and manipulate it, use the WebBrowser object available in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this. I'll give it a try when I get a chance. I'm glad it turn out that I was over complicating things. From the research that I had done, creating an IE extension sounded like a royal pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As EricLaw suggested I am going to use a WebBrowser object to try and perform these actions.